# data filtering on temperature , humidity and air quality raw sensor data

Tags: rest, filter, cassandra, iot

I have several sensors measuring temperature, humidity , and air quality.
The data is collected through an IoT platform and stored to a Cassandra Cluster. For the data distribution to all other applications from Cassandra Cluster, I have created a Rest Api in java.

The data collection scripts are written in C and python . While the Rest Api in java.

My question is the following.

I want to filter my raw sensor data in order to exclude values such as high & low temperatures etc. in order to have as low as possible fault ratio.  have read about the t Kalman Filtering , but I don't want it to happen in real time , I prefer to filter my data straight on the Cassandra nodes.

My best guess right now is to create a service using for ex. java , and filtering data with a time gap excluding the undesirable values.

For example a service that will triggered once a day and it will exclude all the "bad" values from the time of last activation since the last record.

Is there any suggestion for an approach like that?
Or does anyone have a better suggestion ?
Or even better some publication that can guide me through the process .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This heavily depends on the table's design - what are partitions keys, etc.

That use case is quite common, and for such tasks it's better to use Spark with [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc) for most effective reading of the data. If you don't want to use Spark, you'll need to be very careful when implementing the service - don't perform something like `select * from table`, etc., as it will kill cluster.

P.S. I can expand answer if you provide an additional information:

- Schema for tables with infomation
- What operations you'll perform inside that service.